# I keep getting this error and I don't know what it is

Tags: lua, roblox

Ok I made a roblox script that gives a random weapon and it is written in Lua
and I keep getting this error

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function(player)
   local BackPack = player.BackPack
   wait(0.5)
   if player.Leaderstats.Money >= 100 then
      local randomizer = math.random(0,10)
      if randomizer == 1 then
         local knife1 = game.Lighting.CookieKnife:Clone()
         knife1.Parent = BackPack
      elseif randomizer == 2 then
         local knife2 = game.Lighting.Cleaver:Clone()
         knife2.Parent = BackPack
      elseif randomizer == 3 then
         local knife3 = game.Lighting.RustyCleaver:Clone()
         knife3.Parent = BackPack
      elseif randomizer == 4 then
         local knife4 = game.Lighting.WhiteCleaver:Clone()
         knife4.Parent = BackPack
      elseif randomizer == 5 then
         local knife5 = game.Lighting["Sparkley Knife"]:Clone()
         knife5.Parent = BackPack   
      elseif randomizer == 6 then
         local knife6 = game.Lighting.CommonKnife:Clone()
         knife6.Parent = BackPack
      elseif randomizer == 7 then
         local knife7 = game.Lighting.CommonKnife:Clone()
         knife7.Parent = BackPack
      elseif randomizer == 8 then
         local knife8 = game.Lighting.CookieKnife:Clone()
         knife8.Parent = BackPack
      elseif randomizer == 9 then
         local knife9 = game.Lighting.ExpensiveKnife:Clone()
         knife9.Parent = BackPack
      elseif randomizer == 10 then
         local knife10 = game.Lighting.CookieKnife:Clone()
         knife10.Parent = BackPack
      end
   end  
end)
```

Ok I made a roblox script that gives a random weapon and it is written in Lua
and I keep getting this error

> 12:40:50.574 - Players.Player1.PlayerGui.Shop.Main.Frame.RCK.randomweapons2:2: attempt to index global 'player' (a nil value)
>   12:40:50.575 - Stack Begin
>   12:40:50.576 - Script
>   'Players.Player1.PlayerGui.Shop.Main.Frame.RCK.randomweapons2', Line 2
>   12:40:50.576 - Stack End

Comment: the error is not in the provided code...

Comment: Remove `player` from argument list of inner function.  `MouseButton1Click:connect()` expects argument-less function

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff now I'm confused. how can player ever be global if it is an argument of a function?

Comment: @Piglet - Yes, it is unclear if error message is correct of not.  But I'm very sure that it is unlikely that mouse-button-click roblox event would pass some non-mouse data (a `player` value) to mouse event handler.

Comment: that's a very long if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.MouseButton1Click` event doesn't pass the `player` as an argument, define `player` earlier as being `game.Players.LocalPlayer` and you'll avoid the problem you're faced with as the defined `player` is a nil value because no arguments are passed with the event. If your reasoning behind this is because it's a surface/billboard GUI then simply parent the GUI to the player's `PlayerGui` (put it in `StarterGui`) and set the adornee of the GUI to the part it was previously on. Here's the fixed code:

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
   local BackPack = player.BackPack
   wait(0.5)
   if player.Leaderstats.Money >= 100 then
      local randomizer = math.random(0,10)
      if randomizer == 1 then
         local knife1 = game.Lighting.CookieKnife:Clone()
         knife1.Parent = BackPack
      elseif randomizer == 2 then
         local knife2 = game.Lighting.Cleaver:Clone()
         knife2.Parent = BackPack
      elseif randomizer == 3 then
         local knife3 = game.Lighting.RustyCleaver:Clone()
         knife3.Parent = BackPack
      elseif randomizer == 4 then
         local knife4 = game.Lighting.WhiteCleaver:Clone()
         knife4.Parent = BackPack
      elseif randomizer == 5 then
         local knife5 = game.Lighting["Sparkley Knife"]:Clone()
         knife5.Parent = BackPack   
      elseif randomizer == 6 then
         local knife6 = game.Lighting.CommonKnife:Clone()
         knife6.Parent = BackPack
      elseif randomizer == 7 then
         local knife7 = game.Lighting.CommonKnife:Clone()
         knife7.Parent = BackPack
      elseif randomizer == 8 then
         local knife8 = game.Lighting.CookieKnife:Clone()
         knife8.Parent = BackPack
      elseif randomizer == 9 then
         local knife9 = game.Lighting.ExpensiveKnife:Clone()
         knife9.Parent = BackPack
      elseif randomizer == 10 then
         local knife10 = game.Lighting.CookieKnife:Clone()
         knife10.Parent = BackPack
      end
   end  
end)
```

Hope this helps!